# ember.js unit testing and integration testing

Tags: ember.js, qunit, karma-runner

I am exploring ember.js application testing. I came across following blog by Toran Billups
[Integration testing your ember.js app with QUnit and Karma](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/07/21/Integration-testing-your-emberjs-app-with-QUnit-and-Karma/)

When we do `karma start` it runs all the test found in test directory.

How can I run say tests in only one .js file?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bk11425 suggested, simply modify the 'files' section in your karma.conf.js file from this

```
module.exports = function(karma) {
    karma.set({
        basePath: 'js',

        files: [
          "vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js",
          "vendor/handlebars/handlebars.js",
          "vendor/ember/ember.js",
          "vendor/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js",
          "app.js",
          "tests/*.js",
          "templates/*.handlebars"
        ]
```

To something like this instead

```
module.exports = function(karma) {
    karma.set({
        basePath: 'js',

        files: [
          "vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js",
          "vendor/handlebars/handlebars.js",
          "vendor/ember/ember.js",
          "vendor/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js",
          "app.js",
          "tests/mytestfile.js",
          "templates/*.handlebars"
        ]
```

Note- if you are doing integration testing please include the integration helper just above this single test file I showed above

Answer (score 0):

To run the test from just one JS file, specify the file name in the "files" array of your karma config file.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/bkCDL/4eecea53011c95cf9f44) a sample config file I used recently. My example runs 2 js files for the test portion (the last 2 in the list), but you could easily just do one.

Bryan